# Invoking Powershell file blocks referenced Libraries

Tags: c#, powershell, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am executing a Powershell script file from C# with the following code:

```
 Runspace _rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
_rs.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
_rs.Open();
PipeLine _pipeLine = _rs.CreatePipeline();
Command scriptCommand = new Command(filePath);
_pipeLine.Invoke();
```

In the powershell script file I am referencing libraries:

```
Add-Type -Path Filepath.dll
```

In C# i am disposing the runspace and pipeline afterwords trying to unlock the associated libraries.

```
finally
{ 
_rs.Dispose();
_pipeLine.Dispose();
 }
```

Unfortunately in a later step when trying to delete the dll files associated in the script, i get a UnauthorizedException. Please note that i dont get the exception if i never run the script from C#. I def should have accss to it.

Comment: how is yor command bound to pipeline/runspace? I reckon there should be `_pipeLine.Commands.Add()` call?

Comment: Did you run that with elevated mode? It is more of a script holding the usage of the dlls that are associated.best option is to create a separate script to delete the dumps.

Comment: I am adding the command with  `_pipeLine.Commands.Add(scriptCommand)`
@Ranadip could you please elaborate on what you mean by create a seperate script. Do you mean to create a powershell script to delete the associated dlls of the other powershell script?